# Disable a cell when A cell is blank

Tags: google-sheets, data-validation

I want to create a google spreadsheet where I have 2 columns involved.

In my A column, I have data and column B has a drop-down list. What I want to do is disable column B unless column A has a value.

```
Column A1 has value Column B1 is enabled
Column A2 has no value Column B2 is disabled
and so on
```

I created a custom formula:

```
= isblank(A1)
```

Image is:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by disable a cell? Does your data validation works? Is your spreadsheet shared?

Comment: I will have to share the spread sheet to other. By disable I mean I cant be changed/edited..I guess like the disabled button @Rubén

Comment: `=not(isblank(a1))`

Answer (score 1):

all you need is to create a dynamic list of choices by using `IF` and `QUERY`

- set **Data validation** for cell **B1** with criteria **List from a range** to be: **Sheet1!E:E**
- then also chose **Reject input** and hit **<kbd>Save</kbd>** button
- in column **D** put all the stuff you need to have in your **B1** dropdown option (this can be also in different sheet or in a hidden column)
- paste this into **E1** cell: **`=IF(A1="";;QUERY(D1:D;"select D";0))`**
- and now type something in cell **A1**

basically if cell **A1** is empty **B1** is "blocked" with "emptyness"

see sheet here: **[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a0qEXTfaMcWgzOYDCDIO_AyBya5O8-Y0GOSjiasb2uE/edit#gid=0)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On Google Sheets cells can't be disabled  for editors in the same way that buttons are disabled on web page but they can be protected. In order to do this automatically you should use a script triggered by an edit installable trigger or to use an add-on.

Related Q&A

- [How to lock/protect cells in Google Spreadsheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/9062/88163)
- [Script to add protection and remove the user running it?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/95751/88163)

References

- [Protect, hide, and edit sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656?hl=en)

Comment: I will check these as soon as I can.